# Unity3d Как добавить кнопку для элемента массива в инспекторе?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Есть `PropertyDrawer`, все с ним прекрасно, однако я не могу найти способ как добавить к нему `инлайн` кнопку. Приходится пользоваться вместо этого чекбоксом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (InteractiveObject))]
class InteractiveObjectPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty (position, label, property);
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel (position, GUIUtility.GetControlID (FocusType.Passive), label);
        var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;
        Rect colorRect = new Rect (position.x, position.y, 40, position.height);
        Rect unitRect = new Rect (position.x + 50, position.y, 90, position.height);
        Rect nameRect = new Rect (position.x + 150, position.y, position.width - 150, position.height);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUI.PropertyField (colorRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("show"), GUIContent.none);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck() ) {
            RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_highlight", property.FindPropertyRelative ("id").colorValue);
        }
        EditorGUI.PropertyField (unitRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("name"), GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField (nameRect, property.FindPropertyRelative ("name"), GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;
        EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы вместо чекбокса иметь там кнопку

PS: `GuiLayout.Button` не предлагать, он рисует кнопки не в строке свойства, а под всем списком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было найдено вот [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html)

вот код:

```
if (GUI.Button(colorRect, "show")){
    ...
}
```

и скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]